# Where did the following name of Vishnu has been taken from?

Tags: vishnu, name, reference-request

Vishnu can be called by name **[श्रिहान](https://www.moonastro.com/babyname/baby%20name%20shreehan%20meaning.aspx)**. It is not present in Vishnu Sahasranamam.

Which scripture contains the name and what is the actual meaning of it?

[2](https://www.bachpan.com/Meaning-of-Shreehan.aspx), [3](https://www.kidpaw.com/names/shreehan), [4](https://www.tinystep.in/baby-name/Shreehan) ....

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: Are you sure this is the name? search in sanskrit dictionaries don't show any anything.

Comment: @Partha Scriptural source I dont know... I came to know from site for names..... https://www.kidpaw.com/names/shreehan

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, many sites saying that it is name of Vishnu... http://www.moonastro.com/babyname/baby%20name%20shreehan%20meaning.aspx

Comment: I think it is a distorted form of श्रेयान् or श्रीमान्.

Comment: @hanugm "Kid names" sites can't be trusted. They even say non-Sanskrit names as Sanskrit.

Comment: @TheDestroyer But it can be reduced to **Shree+Haan** afaik. May be **haan** can have some meaning in Sanskrit.....

Comment: @hanugm हान means gone or "act of abandoning" which means "without Sri". Not sure if we can give meaning like this. How can this be a name of Vishnu? Vishnu means with Sri or Lakshmi. Looks like अपभ्रंश.

Comment: @TheDestroyer in that case it would be श्रीहान I think and yes that can never mean Sri Vishnu

Comment: @Partha But Sanskrit dictionaries don't show श्रीहान in search results. http://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/sanskrit/index.php This site gets results from various Sanskrit dictionaries and also shows auto suggestions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes, i also did not find any. But as haana is there as is Sri, I think such a word could be constructed as is always done in sanskrit.

Comment: @Partha Kanha is also not a name mentioned in Vishnu Sahasranamam. It comes from word Khan(one-eyed Dajjal/illuminati) and mleccha in origin.

Comment: @Nitin its apabhrangsha of Krishna

Comment: @Nitin its used in charyapads and mentiined in  dictionaries as apabhrangsha

Comment: @Partha many corrupted names and images of Aryana deities are coming from outside like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupati_seal , here you will see, horns on the image of Lord Shiva which is blasphemy, but in reality is an image of Dragon/Rain Man/Cernunnos and his devil's horn used by illuminati. Shiva has only crescent moon not horns :| . Similarly Kanha/Khan(means one-eyed) and is a symbol of illuminati, not a name of Lord Vishnu

Comment: @ManuKumar what does illuminati mean in case of hinduism

Comment: @codeczar illuminati worships Kali, the Satan, explained it https://qr.ae/TWIMfk